# Spark queue name in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to execute my queries in hive using spark engine, but i need to run them in specific queue. I couldn't find any queue name properties except in `spark-submit --queue`. So far i've used these settings:

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set spark.job.queue.name=MyQueue;
set spark.executor.instances=50;
```

or

```
set spark.queue.name=MyQueue;
```

but they won't start the jobs.

found another option:

```
set spark.yarn.queue=MyQueue
```

doesn't work either

Comment: Which version of Hive? Which version of Spark? Do you have Sentry or Ranger enabled? Does your user *(or the `hive` system user if Sentry/Ranger are used to mess with access privileges)* really have access to that queue named `MyQueue`? Did you check in YARN that the jobs were not pending because the queue was misconfigured?

Comment: Did you check *HIVE-12538* and *HIVE-12611* known issues? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12538 + https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12611

Comment: Thanks for help guys, tried to use console got this error: `Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'` looks like our admins our admins didn't set up Hive on Spark.